# Manually inserting a varbinary into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to insert data into a VARBINARY(max) column manually using mssql:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [SomeTable]([varbinary]) 
        Values (0x255044462D312.....Long VARBINARY(max).....CCB6ED46F9)
END
```

However, when it's inserted a extra heading 0 will be added(0x**0**255...) and the trailing 9 will be removed(...46F_) When I later try to use this the contents will be corrupt.

Can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: the data type in your table is varbinary or varbinary(max)?

Comment: It is varbinary(max)

Comment: I'd venture to guess that your hexstring has an odd number of digits, which would at least explain the `0` padding.

Comment: it pads the value with 0 if your pass in odd number of digits

Comment: The hexstring is generated trough OPENROWSET(BULK    and works fine. It's when i copy this value and try to manually insert it in another table this ahppens.

Comment: but reguarding truncation...what is the length of the value you've inserted? That results from table?

Comment: 43679 chars long

Comment: so it should be 43688 but it inserted only 43679?

Comment: >>> It's when i copy this value and try to manually insert it in another table<<< How do you copy it? I think it's copy/paste issue. Why don't you do INSERT..SELECT instead?

Comment: Im running this script on another DB. So can't select from table. The string is same when i copy it double checked.

Comment: it adds a 0 and removes a 9 .    0 at start 9 at end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved,

apparently msssql keeps some internal checksum and adds it to the varbinary so if you copy paste it from the table and try to insert it again sql will be confused and try to "correct" this internal checksum. A workaround is to generate a script from the db where you export the table data. The output in this generated script won't contain the internal checksums and you can use this in updates and inserts etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicit converting:

```
CONVERT(varbinary(max), '00001340132401324...', 2)
```

Last parameter stays for converting type.
Check out Binary Styles section here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

@Grigoryants saved my bacon with your answer and if the varbinary string is a result of an encryption - to view the original string you can use something like

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY key_name
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE cert_name

SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(256), DecryptByKey(CONVERT(varbinary(8000), '00D32FD0BD90 ... 21F1C30',2)))
GO

Just remember to first remove the 0x at the beginning

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35477826)